# How can I data pass from Activity to fragment using Shared View Model in textChangedListener

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

I'm writing dictionary app. I have one activity and three fragment. Activity is including toolbar, tabLayout and viewpager. I added editext in the toolbar.

I want to move the data entered in edittext from activity to the fragment using addChangedListener method. I wrote interface or Shared View Model but I can't capture the data in fragment without pressing the enter key from the keyboard.

Can you help me ?

My onTextChanged method

```
  override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                    searchViewModel.setName(p0.toString())
                }
```

I wrote View Model Class:

class SearchViewModel : ViewModel(){

```
private val mName = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun setName(name: String) {
    mName.value = name
}

fun getName(): LiveData<String>? {
    return mName
}
```

}

and I wrote Fragment Class in onViewCreated method:

```
 pageViewModel = activity.run {
        ViewModelProvider(this!!).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
    }
    pageViewModel.getName()!!.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer<String?> {

            print("ümit $it")
        })
```

Thank you for response, have i good day.

Comment: So this EditText is part of the Activity but you have an override for the onTextChanged

Seems you should instead inside the activity be adding the listener

editText.addTextChangeListener(textWatcher), 
unless you have a custom view or something.. could you add some more code so we have a better idea what you architecture is here

Comment: Hello Tyler, thank your for response. Yes, I added addTextChangeListener for Edittext. I catch data in onTextChanged method. I dont try custom view or something but I research this.